# Equivalence between prediction interval and hypothesis test on Poisson predicted values with 2/3 power transformation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, skewness, quasi-likelihood, poisson-distribution

I fitted a quasi-Poisson regression model to predict the value of a certain counting variable.
Once the predicted value $\widehat{\mu_{0}}$ was obtained, I calculated the upper limit of its prediction interval using the 2/3 power transformation for skewness correction as done by [Farrington et al.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2983331.pdf):
$$
U=\widehat{\mu_{0}}\left[1+\frac{2}{3}z_{\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{\widehat{\mu_{0}}\phi+Var(\widehat{\mu_{0}})}{\widehat{\mu_{0}}^{2}}}\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}
$$
where $\phi$ is the overdispersion parameter and $z_{\alpha}$ is the $100(1-\alpha)$ percentile of the standard normal distribution.
Now, if a given value $x$ is greater than $U$ I'll conclude that $x$ is significantly greater than the predicted value at a $100(1-\alpha)$ confidence level. So, by comparing the upper limit of the prediction interval to a fixed value I am implicitly conducting a hypothesis test. Now, instead of doing so, wich requires me to previously set $\alpha$, how can I directly compute the equivalent test statistic and the respective pvalue?

If there was no 2/3 power transformation I would have no trouble getting the test statistic, but in these conditions I don't see how to do it.